# I want to attenuate my incoming signal whose value is around ±80V to ±0.8V

Tags: adc

[image: Schematic]

I have used this circuit configuration to attenuate the signal. Will this work without clipping the signal? Is there any alternative to this? I have to give signal to ADC as a input whose input voltage signal span is 2 Vpp.

Comment: That depends. Is your goal to attenuate the signal or to blow the top off the op amp IC?

Comment: It will probably do the above, what are you measuring is there a reason you can't use a simple resistor divider?

Comment: my incoming signal is given to CRT display which operates at very high potential, also my signals is of very high frequency. so i have used buffer here to isolate the high frequency component from remaining system. just not sure whether this circuit will reduce my signal to ±0.8V without clipping it .

Answer (score -1):

R76/R75 = 1/99
no need to use any op-amp

R76 = 100K +-1%
R75 = 1.01 K +-1% practically 1 K +-1%

Comment: It would help if you explained to the user (and future viewers) exactly what you mean by this answer.  An experienced engineer might understand, but many would appreciate a small circuit diagram and short explanation.

Comment: Just using resistors increases output impedance which means loading will affect signal. May or may not be an issue